# Why did this find exec ls stop showing one of the files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I had a find + ls showing me the .sh and .sh.bak of a couple of files.

I copied one of them thinking I'd then have 3 files but,
the ls quit showing one of them, the .sh.bak

I was repeating the find + ls from the history and I've since compared the copies

Looking at 2 files:

```
[root@localhost jeos]# find / -name del-non-*-locales.sh* -execdir ls -lh {} \;  
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4.4K Dec 17  2016 /root/proj/vm/locale/backups/del-non-eng-locales.sh.bak  
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4.4K Dec 17  2016 /root/proj/host.setup/manual/del-non-english-locales.sh
```

Copied 1

```
[root@localhost jeos]# cp ~/proj/host.setup/manual/del-non-english-locales.sh .
```

up arrow + enter ... thought I'd see 3 files now

```
[root@localhost jeos]# find / -name del-non-*-locales.sh* -execdir ls -lh {} \;  
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4.4K Dec 17  2016 /root/proj/host.setup/manual/del-non-english-locales.sh  
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4.4K Nov  9 11:05 /root/proj/jeos/del-non-english-locales.sh
```

The find + ls didn't change & the file it quit showing is here:

```
[root@localhost jeos]# ls -lh /root/proj/vm/locale/backups/del-non-eng-locales.sh.bak  
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4.4K Dec 17  2016 /root/proj/vm/locale/backups/del-non-eng-locales.sh.bak
```

Comment: So… What's the question?

Comment: Have you considered quoting `del-non-*-locales.sh*`?

Comment: @Satō Katsura yes ... to constrain the globbing or something or other. Nice Catch. I tested it, commenting it worked :)

If you make your comment an Ans I'll check it off and call this Q a wrap.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller I'm not happy with your edits; they changed the meaning of what I was saying. Can you revert them? Please do.

I want -execdir, not -exec (softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml)

The behavior, was corrected by putting quotes around a wildcarded parm.
That's a fix for a bash behavior, ... globbing or expansion or somesuch .... 

The the problem appeared in a use of the find command but it was about understanding bash, the shell, actually: how it presents input to the command. So the tags you removed, bash and shell ... can you undo that?

Comment: My apologies; I had sent in an edit, but it didn’t go through until after your revision. I’ve rolled my edit back to yours.

Comment: There is nothing specific to bash here, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You need to quote `del-non-*-locales.sh*`.**

The first run works because you don't have any file in the current directory matching `del-non-*-locales.sh*`, so by default the pattern expands to itself (with stars and all).

After you copy `~/proj/host.setup/manual/del-non-english-locales.sh` to the current directory, `del-non-*-locales.sh*` expands to `del-non-english-locales.sh`, so you're actually searching for that exact name, not for `del-non-*-locales.sh*`.  That's why `del-non-eng-locales.sh.bak` no longer matches.